# More Threads or Empty Loops?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop

In Java, which is considered more taxing? Implementing another thread and using wait notify or incorporating a for/while loop inside a current thread similar to this >

```
while(running){

 //do stuff

   if(skip == 20){

      //do more stuff
      skip = 0;

   }else{
      skip++;
   }
   }
```

I'm gonna guess the latter is not considered best practice but I don't want to end up spending too much memory on an extra thread that does very little.

Comment: Did you happen to notice when you try that the fans on your machine come on really loud as you burn up an entire core at 100% utilization? Aside from that, assuming you have a sleep somewhere or this isn't an infinite loop ... threads are meant for *parallelization* of work. If you don't need that or it doesn't apply to your problem, you don't use additional threads.

Comment: For the sake of your processor, use a new thread.  You're gonna bring the poor thing to its knees like this.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'll take that as an answer xD (btw its phone, no cooling fans)

Comment: @BrianRoach android tag and fans don't usually come together :)

Comment: Doh! Missed that. Even worse, you just created a hand warmer!

Comment: @BrianRoach its rather pleasant actually =P

Comment: it depends on what you are doing

Comment: @BrianRoach etc. - I assume 'stuff' contains blocking operations eg. I/O, inter-thread comms.  I don't see any reason to assume it's a CPU-loop.

Comment: @MartinJames - I try not to make assumptions and just work with what is posted. Sometimes my humor doesn't come across in text; some of that was in jest. I think Jack got it (Touche on the hand warmer response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(moved to being an answer)

Assuming you have a sleep somewhere or this isn't an infinite loop ... threads are meant for parallelization of work; e.g. you want to do two things at the same time on two different cores. If you don't need that or it doesn't apply to your problem, you don't use additional threads.

If you don't have a sleep or other blocking operation and it is an infinite loop, you just created a hand warmer app (or a battery drainer app ...)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the flow you need, ie 'stuff' and 'more stuff' are not expected to run in parallel, then the counter/skip loop is fine - don't go near signaling other threads just to run 'more stuff' after every 20 'stuff'.

Comment: is that so? It doesn't seem to be what the others are saying. Does it depend on how much "more stuff" there is?

Comment: @KrzysztofKozielczyk Okay if I just want a delay then threads is the answer?

Comment: @Jack Sorry, I deleted my comment in the meantime. I realized I didn't really understand the question (I don't think it contains enough data yet). If `do stuff` is meaningful work that takes significant time then I agree with Martin's suggestion and the loop should be fine. If it is trivial code that takes no time then you're going to create hand warmer as @BrianRoach pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer but I would like to suggest a principle to follow. Each iteration of your loop should include a blocking operation, and the blocking operation should have a timeout so that it doesn't block forever. If you don't have any blocking operation you could use sleep (or better, wait for an event with a timeout, see below).

If you want to improve the responsibility of breaking your main loop use an event instead of a `bool` flag to control the main loop. This way when the event is signaled the loop will break immediately. In pseudo-code:

```
while(!wait_for(cancelLoopEvent, immediate))
{
    // do stuff

    if(time_to_work())
    {
        // do the work
    }
    else
    {
        wait_for(cancelLoopEvent, loop_timeout)
    }
}
```